# Getting values inside jquery from input fields with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get value of input fields with dynamic id to jquery function

```html
<input type="text" id="a_8" name="a_8" value="12">
<input type="text" id="b_8" name="b_8" value="22">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:det(8);">Submit</button>

<input type="text" id="a_9" name="a_9" value="22">
<input type="text" id="b_9" name="b_9" value="52">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:det(9);">Submit</button>
```

Jquery function

```html
function det(a)
{
//how can I get values of id a_8,b_8  when first button is clicked
and a_9,b_9 values when second button is clicked
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply create id of your control by appending method argument a to a_ or b_ like $("#a_"+a).val()

```js
function det(a)
{
  alert($("#a_"+ a ).val());
  alert($("#b_"+ a ).val());
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a_8" name="a_8" value="12">
<input type="text" id="b_8" name="b_8" value="22">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:det(8);">Submit</button>

<input type="text" id="a_9" name="a_9" value="22">
<input type="text" id="b_9" name="b_9" value="52">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:det(9);">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function det(a){
        var b1 = $('#a_'+a).val();
        var b2 = $('#b_'+a).val();
        console.log('values: '+b1+','+b2);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a_8" name="a_8" value="12">
<input type="text" id="b_8" name="b_8" value="22">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:det(8);">Submit</button>

<input type="text" id="a_9" name="a_9" value="22">
<input type="text" id="b_9" name="b_9" value="52">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:det(9);">Submit</button>
```